# How to recover local Notes data from external backup (Time Machine)

Tags: time-machine, notes.app, data-recovery, sonoma

I accidentally deleted my local Notes. I attempted to recover them from Time Machine backup but encountered an issue where Notes crashed after some seconds and my recovered notes were discarded after the first attempt.

I know there are several posts here on how to recover the data and I read a lot. My problem is how to do it so Notes does not crash after the recovery and discard my data again.

#### What I Need

I'm looking for a way to recover my notes, even if it's just for a single export.

#### How The Loss Happened

I had disabled the syncing of Notes to iCloud. Following this, both my local Notes and iCloud notes were empty. The local and iCloud trash were also empty, and there were no Notes entries in the recovery section.

#### What Happens After a Restore

I have a Time Machine backup, and I've found some posts on how to recover Notes from these backups. Here's what occurs when I attempt to recover them and start Notes:

- My old content briefly appears for a few seconds. Notes **crashes**
- Notes creates a backup of the Sqlite files in a subfolder
- A dialog box with the message "Notes Quit Unexpectedly" appears.
- When I start Notes again, all entries are gone.

#### Recovery Methods Tried

Before attempting these recoveries, I disabled iCloud sync for Notes, and I also tried them with sync enabled. Here are the recovery methods I've attempted:

- Recovering just the NoteStore.sqlite files.
- Recovering the entire folder `~/Library/Group Containers/group.com.apple.notes/NoteStore.sqlite`
- Recovering the folder mentioned above and the following notes folders:

  - `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes.datastore`
  - `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes.HTMLConverter`
  - `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes.LPPreviewGenerator`
  - `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Notes.NotesImporter`
- Recovering the entire user profile.
- Installing a clean macOS and then recovering the entire user profile.

The recovery is successful, Notes shows the wanted content and crashes after some seconds. Then the content is gone again.

Example of a crash report

```
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Notes [25400] Path:                 
/System/Applications/Notes.app/Contents/MacOS/Notes Identifier:       
com.apple.Notes Version:               4.11 (2463) Build Info:        
Notes-2463000000000000~8 Code Type:             X86-64 (Native) Parent
Process:        launchd [1] User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-11-20 10:56:25.4581 +0100 OS Version:     
macOS 14.1.1 (23B81) Report Version:        12 Bridge OS Version:    
8.1 (21P1069) Anonymous UUID:        D3181C25-EF12-257C-E710-9F56C23BA1C7


Time Awake Since Boot: 45000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        12

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL) Exception Codes:  
0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 4 Illegal instruction: 4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [25400]
```